# Parent component listen focus on input contained in child component

Tags: angular, parent-child, communication, angular-components, onfocus

I have a component (child) in a page html of an other component (parent) like that:

```
<div>
   <child-component (focusEmit)="startAnimation()"></child-component>
</div>
```

In child component there is an input:

```
<input type="text" (focus)="focusFunction()"/>
```

the focusFunction() emit an event to the parent which does something.

I don't want resolve this use case in this way. I would that the child component is clean (cause I have other nested component, this use case is simplified, and I don't want a long chain of output emit).

There is an other way which is the parent to catch the event focus in an input contained in his children component?

Answer (score 0):

You can use Subject (rxJs) http://reactivex.io/rxjs/manual/overview.html#subject
which is an alternate to EventEmitter.

---

Through @Output eventEmitter it can be done this way

Child Component

```
@Output() focusEmit = new EventEmitter<any>();

focusFunction() {
   this.focusEmit.emit(true);
}
```

Parent Component

Html

```
 <child-component (focusEmit)="startAnimation(event)"></child-component>
```

component.ts

```
startAnimation($event) {
    // Handle your code
}
```

---

**With ViewChild pattern**

Parent Component

```
<child-component  #childAttr></child-component>

@ViewChild("childAttr") childAttr;
childAttrId : string;

startAnimation() {
    this.childAttrId  = childAttr.id;
}
```

But your child component remains same

```
focusFunction() {
   this.id = "focus triggered";
}
```

Comment: I would not to pass through a service. At this point I'd prefer use emit event.

Comment: Oh okie then, I will modify my answer to handle eventEmitter

Comment: Sorry, maybe I has been not clear. This is already my solution. But I ask if there are other solutions in which is the parent to catch the event contained in his children component. In this way the children stay clean and the parent handler the event.

Comment: If you are interested to handle it through events, then it is the only way.

Comment: You can use @ViewChild as well. I will edit my answer with viewChild

Comment: No, when I say  "event" I am referring to the event "onFocus", but I would know if there is a way in which is only the parent to handler this situation. Maybe through ViewChild or something else. I don't know if there is a better solution, for this I made this question.

Comment: ViewChild is the one you exactly need. Parent will access the child variables and child will hold the event like onFocus.

Comment: However, as I explained, this use case is (very) semplified. I have nested children and only the last child has this input. But it's ok. I remain with my inititial solution with eventEmitter that seems the best for now.